# Delphi 2009 Korzh Localizer performance issue

Tags: delphi, localization

I'm developing an application for Windows with Delphi 2009. For localization i'm using the Korzh Localizer (http://devtools.korzh.com/localizer/).

Everything works fine except one thing: when i want to compile the project, Localizer is building multiple times the entire project (3-5 times). Are there any known solutions to provide faster compile times for testing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ask the vendor? Post on their forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Localizer do you use?
Try to turn off "Refresh on Build" option for your project.

Comment: Hello Sergiy, thank you for your answer. I have tried it out and now the project is buildt only twice. Thanks a lot. (By the way: i'm using version 4.8.0.69 with Delphi 2009...)